# Installing Android ADT on 64-bit Linux

Tags: java, android

For Linux 64-bit (opensuse 13.1), what is the correct version of Java to install to used the Android ADT? The Android developer website cites Oracle Java 1.6, other resources say used the latest Oracle Java. Also, it is unclear which Java to install on a 64-bit system for Android development. Some resources claim the 32-bit Java must be installed on a 64-bit system while others claim 64-bit Java on a 64-bit system. Help with the correct info for my platformed is appreciated.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 64bit Linux install 64bit java. [jdk link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

Oracle is providing different version for Linux. 
For ADT you can go through the general note section in the ADT link.Recommendable is Jdk 1.6 & later.
[ADT link](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Dexter, there's nothing special needed for a 64 bit machine, most of the android adt will work except few adb dependencies

You can still use open jdk 1.6 or 1.7 64 bit and use 64 bit version eclipse

But you will have to install `ia32-libs` (not necessarily entire i386 package)

If you want to just install the components used in adt then launch eclipse in debug mode and take note on logs for the libs missing which would be mostly `lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6`

> sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6

which will enable adb and its related 32 bit android dependencies without all the unnecessary packages which will come bundled if you do an `apt-get install ia32-libs`

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to follow the AOSP recomendations. They say install v1.6. You can do that by using the webupd repository. If you add the Webupd repository and install the oracle java installer via apt-get it will automatically install the x64 version of Java on your x64 system. I have Java 1.6 x64 and ADT x64 on my Ubuntu 12.04 x64 and it works perfectly. Also remember you have to install all the packages that are listed on the AOSP page.

Answer (score 0):

I've used 64-bit open-1.6 for a long time with no problems. Recently, I had an unrelated need to use 1.7 and switched to that and have had no problems.